# Having worked in industry for a few years, do I need someone from the industry to recommend me when applying for MS in CS by thesis?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters

During my undergraduate studies, I published a paper and gained some experience in research. Unfortunately, I didn't take up my higher education immediately but instead worked in the software industry for 3 years straight.

At work, my nature of job did not involve any research. However, I became passionate about solving a group of problems which I encountered and discovered that there are several active fronts in research. I have decided to go back to academia and apply for a MS in CS by thesis program.

As letters of recommendation are an important component to gain the admission into a good university, I have been sceptical about getting a recommendation from someone in industry since it is for a thesis based program. Will an admission committee of a university be interested in reading a recommendation from someone from the industry or would it be advisable to get all my recommendations from my professors (it's been 3 years since they worked with me)?

Comment: Have a read of other similar LoR questions - https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27695/recommendation-letter-from-a-non-phd-referee?rq=1, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/59548/is-a-letter-of-recommendation-from-an-employer-useful-when-the-company-has-shut?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/60751/us-master-admissions-lor-academic-vs-employer?rq=1, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/78552/letters-of-recommendation-only-from-employers-and-managers?rq=1

Comment: @Poidah, thanks for sharing these links. They are pretty useful.